# sql: Inserting new column to the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have added a new column to my admin table.I want to populate revision column against effective_date column.

```
        ALTER TABLE home.prod ADD revision int;
```

The revision number will start with 100 and increment by 1.  The revisions will be based on the effective_date.  So, the oldest eff_date, will get 100, then next oldest will get 101, and so on.

```
          Eff date 1/1/2012 – Revision 100
          Eff date 1/1/2013 – Revision 101
          Eff date 7/1/2014 – Revision 102
          Eff date 1/1/2015 – Revision 103
```

something like this statement-

```
          revision =100
          UPDATE prod.admin 
          SET revision= revision+ 1
          WHERE eff_date = /'
```

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using? MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can do

```
UPDATE prod.admin 
CROSS JOIN (select @rev := 99) r
SET revision = (@rev := @rev + 1)
ORDER BY eff_date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't allow `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` query with `ORDER BY`.  One method is:

```
SELECT @rn := 99;

UPDATE prod.admin 
    SET revision = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    ORDER BY eff_date ASC;
```

If you can assume that `@rn` starts with a `NULL` value, you can do:

```
UPDATE prod.admin 
    SET revision = (@rn := COALESCE(@rn, 100), @rn + 1)
    ORDER BY eff_date ASC;
```

In SQL Server, you would do:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eff_date) as seqnum
      FROM prod.admin
     )
update toupdate
    SET revision = seqnum;
```